# Does SSL have anything built in that can detect a dropped connection?

Tags: ssl

Consider this scenario:

```
[wanting to write]       [sent token success] 
Application -------> SSL ----------->
                                     | *peer drops*
              [waiting to read]      | 
           ***blocked***<------------
```

In other words, your application wants to write something, but the SSL internal state is WANT_READ. On the other end, the peer connection has dropped.

Can SSL detect this through some keep-alive check of it's own? What can you do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL usually leaves detection of connection problems to the underlying transport layer, i.e. TCP. This means that by using [TCP keep alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) it can be detected if the peer vanishes without proper connection close. Apart from that there is also the [heartbeat extension](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55215/why-does-tls-need-an-explicit-heartbeat-protocol) at the TLS level but contrary to TCP keep alive it is not universally supported.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this. Yes, I am looking into using TCP keep alive to handle this case. I'm surprised that there isn't something built into the protocol to handle it.

Comment: @minus: first there is the TLS heartbeat extension, although their main purpose is probably DTLS (i.e. over unreliable UDP). But more important: why add some detection for transport layer problems into the session layer, especially since there is already a detection at the transport layer one simply has to use (i.e. TCP keep alive).

Comment: True. And in my case, I can use the heartbeat extension.

Answer (score 0):

If SSL detects a connection that hasn't been correctly terminated from SSL's point of view via an SSL `close_notify` message, it will regard it as a truncation attack, and will give you an error message or an exception, depending on which API you are using.

> your application wants to write something, but the SSL internal state is WANT_READ. On the other end, the peer connection has dropped.

What it wants you to read is either the `close_notify` or the error message or exception. Whatever the case, when it says WANT_READ, you have to read.

Comment: I understand the question is about the case that the connection is dropped, that is no proper close but the client simply vanishes (i.e. system crash, router/firewall state expires...). In this case the SSL read will just hang until the underlying TCP connection signals an error. And without TCP keep alive or socket timeouts (i.e. default case) this error will not happen.